# How many rigid 4-regular graphs are there?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, rigidity

I am interested in any formulas for the number of globally rigid 4-regular graphs, or Laman graphs of degree at most 4, on $n$ vertices. The bound can be for graphs with labeled or unlabeled vertices.

Comment: Various types of Laman graphs are enumerated at https://oeis.org/search?q=laman&language=english&go=Search but not, I think, the ones asked for here.